# How can I check if printer has no paper using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to print more than one page from the web. I use JavaScript to print pages.
How can we check whether the printer has any paper using JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you want to check that? You always want to send the job to the printer. The printer will tell the user if it requires paper or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. That would require access to the printer driver of the local machine. You can't even get out of the browser, let alone anything else.

This kind of behaviour should be left to the local machine anyway. Once the print job has been sent it's out of your hands.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're talking about an intranet application, you could write your own communications protocol for controlling, monitoring, and diagnosing your printers paper feed. Similar things were done before, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol.

Mixing in some asynchronous status calls before invoking `window.print` and you should be good to go.

If that's to much hassle, you probably should bet on the users ability to refill their printers paper.